# How to add back button that says "Back"

Tags: android, user-interface, back

I have a working back button, but it is simply an arrow pointing to the left. It has no icon, so it is rather thin.

I want to add text to it, as seen in this iOS screenshot:

[image]

I *can* add text to the title bar, but you have to click on the tiny arrow to get it to go back.

I can't find any XML or code solutions. **How do I add text to my back button?**

Comment: Have you seen any Android apps that have this "back button with text"? I haven't. So maybe Android doesn't have this function.

Comment: Why not add the text to the image you're using for your button? Does the text change?

Comment: @Sweeper Facebook messenger does. When you're in a conversation, the back button has the text of the name of the person you're chatting with.

Comment: @CaptJak I guess that would technically work but it feels hacky. Seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. You could make the button have the text you want, leave the arrow as an image, and then set the alpha of the button (with the text)  to 0 and overlap the image. I don't know of a built in way, so this is just more hackery...

Answer (score 1):

Add in your onCreate of your activity:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then you can customize the back event at onOptionsItemSelected like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //Finish activity.
            finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Then in your AppManifest.xml, you have inside your activity tag an attribute called `android:label="Notes"`.

where "Notes" will be the title of your activity that will be shown in the ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Found a great solution! Custom views for action bars. This means you don't have to set the label for your activity to something undescriptive (like "Back").

[enter link description here](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android)

> ### custom_actionbar.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="50dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/black_pattern" >
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/title_text"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>         android:textAllCaps="true"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>         android:textColor="#fff"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="35dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/imageButton"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>         android:background="@null"
>         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate" />
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```
>
> ### MainActivity.java
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>       ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
>       mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
>       mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
>       LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
>
>       View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
>       TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
>       mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");
>
>       ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
>               .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
>       imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>           @Override
>           public void onClick(View view) {
>               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
>                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>           }
>       });
>
>       mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
>       mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
>   }
>
> }
> ```